# Stream audio to Ubuntu via DLNA

Tags: sound, lan, dlna

I'd like to know if there is a way to stream audio from my Android to my computer speaker system via my LAN (DLNA/UPnP).

I discovered an app called [AirAudio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.airaudio&hl=en) that can connect to a device so now I just need to set up my computer to recieve and play it loud on my speakers. I use normal 3.5mm jacks all setup as Front Pair with Alsajackretask

*Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome x64, Pixel 2 XL - Android P beta-dp5, rooted*